# How to use Angular-Charts JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

Apart from the documentation I read (usually not helpful), I found some chart examples I want to implement to my page, but it seems not working. I tried to tweak it around but every time it gets load, it always displaying blank on the page.

Here's the code:

```
<div data-ng-controller="LineCtrl as line">
<canvas> data-sys-chart-line
        data-dataset="line.data"
        width="400"
        height="240"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        function LineCtrl ( ) {
            this.data = {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [40, 10, 60, 70, 20, 20]
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [30, 70, 40, 90, 60, 70]
                }
            ]
        };
    }
})();
</script>
<!-- Includes Dependencies here: AngularJS & Chart.js -->
<script src="script/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="script/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/tc-angular-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

I included those .js files under `/script` folder in my project folder.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Your canvas closing tag is doubled, maybe the width and height properties are not being parsed by the browser, resulting in a blank page. Try <canvas data-sys-chart-line data-dataset="line.data" width="400" height="240"></canvas>

Comment: @WouterCoebergh that was a typo tho.

Comment: @Sajeetharan no error, its just unable to draw

Answer (score 0):

i have never used Chart.js before but seems that u are doing it wrong

you have never initialize the chart, by reading the documentation like for 10 second i found that you have to initialize it like this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("here_is_the_canvas_element").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { ... })
```

and you are using Chart.js code before you include the library